# C opening file from console

Tags: c

I have a simple code that opens a file from hdd in read mode, but the path of the file is already given in the code.I want the user to manually provide the file name,path and file open type through console. What do I have to do for that?

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main() { 
   FILE *fp; 
   fp = fopen("D:\\samplefile.txt","r");     
   if(fp != NULL) { 
      printf("File has been opened");         
      fclose(fp); 
   }     
   else printf("File not found"); 
   return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use of function scanf is done here as an simple use. There are other ways also to get input from user
#include<stdio.h> 
int main()
{
  FILE *fp; 
  char filePath[100];
  printf("Enter Path name: ");
  scanf("%s", filePath);
  printf("value is %s",filePath);
   fp = fopen(filePath,"r");     
    if(fp != NULL) { 
      printf("File has been opened");         
      fclose(fp); 
   }     
   else printf("File not found"); 
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: but how do I input the file open type r,w or a? I can't seem to put anything inside the ".."

Comment: Below answer should fix this issue. you can give input as in r w or rw . Don't input any spaces which you give in your input

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fp; 
  char filePath[100],filePermission[10];
  printf("Enter Path name: ");
  scanf("%s", filePath);
  printf("Enter file permission parameters: ");
  scanf("%s", filePermission);

   fp = fopen(filePath,filePermission);     
   if(fp != NULL) { 
      printf("File has been opened");         
      fclose(fp); 
   }     
   else printf("File not found"); 
   return 0; 

}
```